# ios/uipickerview: How would I have a picker view for US states

Tags: ios, uipickerview

IOS newb with web programming background.

In html I am used to drop down boxes with states (i.e. AK,AL,CA,MA,NY,NJ, etc.) using the select statement.  What is the equivalent syntax using UIpickerview?  I know how to put the picker view in storyboard but don't know how to get all the states to show up in the picker and then capture the selected state.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have put the pickerView in StoryBoard, create an IBOutlet in your ViewController, and one array of states

```
@IBOutlet weak var myPicker: UIPickerView!
var states = ["state1", "state2","state3"]
var selectedState = ""
```

Set the delegate and data source of your pickerView

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myPicker.dataSource = self
    myPicker.delegate = self
}
```

Call the delegate methods:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return states.count
}
```

To place the data in the picker:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
   return states[row]
}
```

And to capture the selected state:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
   selectedState = states[row]
}
```

**EDIT for ObjC**

Creating the outlet and setting the delegate and datasource for pickerView are quite similar: Here are the delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return ([states count]);
}
```

To place the data in the picker:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return ([states objectAtIndex: row]);
}
```

And to capture the selected state:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

selectedState = ([states objectAtIndex:row]);
}
```

Comment: This code looked so clean, for a moment, it did not make any sense until I realized it is Swift. Looks right so I marked it correct but am actually working in Objective C.  Could you translate to Obj C?

Comment: I have added the ObjectiveC code, but as I don't work on ObjC, pls inform if you find any syntax error.

Comment: I'm working inside of a .xib instead of a Storyboard and while running, I navigate to the page with my pickerView and it crashes based on an issue with a scrollView. Any thoughts?

Comment: I will suggest to Ask a New Question, and provide the details, so that its possible to understand and sort out the issue.